# Problem with findOne() in sequelize node.js

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a problem with node.js and sequelize findOne(). I want to find new students, that I want to add to the DB (var novi), and the ones that already exist, I just want to update their field (var stari). Everything works as expected, only when I want to return JSON with how many new students I added to the DB, and how many are updated, values of stari and novi,  go back to 0, but the counting is good, I checked. I know the problem is with asynchronous call, but I don't know how to fix.

```
app.post('/student', function(req,res) {
  var imeGodine = req.body['godina'];
  //POMOĆNE SKRIPTE BitBucket.js i citanjeGodina.js
  var broj = 0;
  var stari = 0;
  var novi = 0;
  db.godina.findOne({where:{nazivGod:req.body.godina}}).then(god => {
    var studenti = req.body.studenti;
    db.student.count().then (ranijeStudenata => {
      for(var i = 0; i<studenti.length; i++) {
        var ime = studenti[i].imePrezime;
        var ind = studenti[i].index;
        db.student.findOne({where:{index :studenti[i].index}}).then(stud => {
          if (stud == null) {
            novi++;
            db.student.create({imePrezime:ime, index : ind}).then(noviStudent => {
              god.addStudenti(noviStudent);
            });
          }
          else if (stud != null) {
            stari++;
            god.addStudenti(stud); 
          }
        });
        broj++;
      }
      var brojNovih = broj - ranijeStudenata; //ne koristi se, ali možda hoće   
      res.set("Content-Type", "application/json");
      res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify({message: "Dodano je " + novi + " novih studenata i upisano " + stari  + " na godinu " + imeGodine}));
    });
  });
});
```

[Picture of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYTDH.png)

Comment: Please show us some code.

Comment: There is a picture of code. I couldn't post different way :(
EDIT ---- I just added code,sorry

Comment: check my answer, if it works, I will update it to explain what you did wrong.

Comment: It doesn't work,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) to do counting in a synchronous way.

```
'use strict';

app.post('/student', async function (req, res) {
  var imeGodine = req.body['godina'];
  var {studenti} = req.body;

  var broj = 0;
  var stari = 0;
  var novi = 0;

  let god = await db.godina.findOne({where: {nazivGod: req.body.godina}});
  let ranijeStudenata = await db.student.count(); // ranijeStudenata not used?

  for (var i = 0; i < studenti.length; i++) {
    var ime = studenti[i].imePrezime;
    var ind = studenti[i].index;

    let stud = await db.student.findOne({where: {index: studenti[i].index}});

    if (stud === null) {
      novi++;
      let noviStudent = await  db.student.create({imePrezime: ime, index: ind});
      god.addStudenti(noviStudent);
    } else if (stud !== null) {
      stari++;
      god.addStudenti(stud);
    }

    broj++;
  }

  return res.status(200).send({
    message: "Dodano je " + novi + " novih studenata i upisano " + stari + " na godinu " + imeGodine
  });

});
```